# Can't read the labels on a hierarchical clustering plot

Tags: r, plot

I am in 2 weeks into programming into R, and I am doing hierarchical clustering (using agnes) on a set of 150 documents.  When I do the clustering, the plot looks really bad as all of the labels overlap, it basically looks like a mess.  What is the best way to

- create a larger plot that I can zoom in if need be to read labels
- creating smaller font, that is also readable

Here's the code I'm using

```
 cluster<- agnes(sim_matrix,diss="TRUE",method="ward")
 dimnames(sim_matrix) = list(docnames, docnames)
 plot(cluster)
```

Answer (score 3):

Save the output to a file:

```
pdf(file="dendrogram.pdf", height=10, width=30)
plot(cluster, which.plots=2, cex=1)
dev.off()
```

Change the `height` and `width` of the pdf until the labels and the dendrogram are visible. You can also adjust font size via `cex` argument.

If you prefer the PNG or other file formats, check `?png`

Comment: @user2680293, does this solution work for you? If so, you may consider accepting the answer by clicking on the green checkmark under the vote arrows. Alternatively, feel free to comment on any remaining issues. Thanks